# onSharedPreferenceChanged not updating preference

Tags: java, android, preferences

So I am trying to update values in my timers.java class when a preference is changed.  Here is the value  in my timers.java

```
final boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPref.getBoolean(spawnTimers.KEY_PREF_SOUND, false);
```

I have called that in the onCreate and if I change a preference, go back 2 screens to main.java and then relaunch timers.java the change will work, however if i just go into preferences and then back out to timers.java the change does not take effect

Here is my settingsFragment.java

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class settingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public static final String KEY_PREF_SOUND_SETTINGS = "pref_key_sounds_settings";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        onSharedPreferenceChanged(null, "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {

        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_SOUND_SETTINGS))
        {
            boolean soundEnabledPref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(spawnTimers.KEY_PREF_SPAWNSOUND, false);
        }
    }



}
```

im guessing what i have in onSharedPreferenceChanged is not correct?  Not really sure what i need to put into the If statement to get the value change of the boolean back to timers.java

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:  someone posted an answer which sort of fixed the problem

I have changed my onSharedPreferencesChanged to

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {

        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_SPAWN_SOUNDS))
        {
            CheckBoxPreference soundEnabledPref = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference(KEY_PREF_SOUND_SETTINGS);
            soundEnabledPref.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(spawnTimers.KEY_PREF_SPAWNSOUND, false));
        }
    }
```

This now updates the value and it is working, however, whenever i check or uncheck the box, it is throwing an  error

```
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681): Process: com.rcd.helper, PID: 3681
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.preference.PreferenceCategory cannot be cast to android.preference.CheckBoxPreference
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at com.rcd.helper.settingsFragment.onSharedPreferenceChanged(settingsFragment.java:43)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:475)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:385)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java:1372)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.Preference.persistBoolean(Preference.java:1638)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.setChecked(TwoStatePreference.java:84)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onClick(TwoStatePreference.java:70)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:952)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-24 13:35:36.558: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are the keys the same. `spawnTimers.KEY_PREF_SOUND` and `spawnTimers.KEY_PREF_SPAWNSOUND` ??

Comment: No they are not.  KEY_PREF_SOUND is the preference category key, and KEY_PREF_SPAWNSOUND is the CheckBoxPreference key

Comment: Are you sure that `KEY_PREF_SOUND_SETTINGS` is a checkboxPreference?

Comment: It is not.  I actually changed it to the KEY_PREF_SPAWN_SOUNDS (which is the key for the checkbox) and that made the error go away, but I am back to, the boolean not being changed in my timer.java

I am guessing the reason it changed before was due to the soft crash

Comment: for some reason, it is still only changing if i change it in preferences, go back 2 screens to main.java and relaunch timers.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `onSharedPreferenceChanged` manually and passing it null and empty String as arguements?

Remove `onSharedPreferenceChanged(null, "");`from your code.

Comment: That was added in there from a tutorial i was trying to get it fixed.. i removed it but it actually wasnt doing anything (as far as I can tell)  Someone previously posted an "answer" which I implemented and it half works.

will post the update above

Comment: Any further ideas?  I am able to get through the If statement in the public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) and both the onPause and onResume are firing, so whatever ive got in the onSharedPreferencesChanged is not actually changing the preference value which is stored in timers.java

Comment: Do I need to put an intent in there in order to pass the value back to timers.java?